# Linux mount and save changes to RAM (while not changing the underlying file system)

Tags: linux, mount, readonly

I am looking for a way to discard any changes written to a filesystem.
Currently, I am mounting a file system with `mount -o ro`. If programs write to it, an error will be raised. I would like to change the behavior so that the changes are saved to RAM and discarded on unmount. How would I do that?

Comment: Have you consider of using kind of snapshot of the filesystem?

Comment: I have, but that would not work, since the underlying image is accessed by many processes.

Comment: If you have enough RAM you can consider RAM disk (created from the physical one)

Comment: ramdisk, btrfs, zfs, bcachefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use [an overlay](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html): this can combine one (or more) “lower” read-only file system(s) with an (optional) read-write “upper” file system. Writes go to the upper file system, and reads are handled by whichever file system actually has the relevant data.

You need to make the your read-only file system available somewhere; here I’ll use `/mnt/sourcedata`. Then create a `tmpfs` which will be used as the overlay:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/overlay
sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/overlay
```

This needs an upper directory and a work directory:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/overlay/{upper,work}
```

For this example the merged file system will be exposed in `/mnt/merged`; you need to replace this by whatever the target is in your scenario:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/merged
```

Finally, merge everything:

```
sudo mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/mnt/sourcedata,upperdir=/mnt/overlay/upper,\
workdir=/mnt/overlay/work /mnt/merged
```